# KnockoutJS - Using custom bindings to add animation

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to make use of custom bindings to display a progress icon (spinner or bar) whilst a price is being updated via an ajax call.

Before I started using Knockout I just called onUpdating() at the start of my ajax method and then onUpdated(price) when the ajax successfully returned a price.

```
function onUpdating() {
    $(".price").empty().html('<img src="/Content/Img/Site/progress.gif" />');
}

function onUpdated(price) {
    $(".price").empty().html('£' + price);
}
```

As I'm now using Knockout I'd like to use the custom bindings but I just cant get my head around how it works.

I guess something like this:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.showProgress = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).empty().html('<img src="/Content/Img/Site/progress.gif" />');
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).empty().html('£' + valueAccessor());
        }
    }

<p>
    Price: <span data-bind="showProgress: price"></span>
</p>
```

However, this doesn't work at all. Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
The following seems to be getting there but its not showing the progress bar whilst updating:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.showProgress = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).empty().html('<img src="/Content/Img/Site/progress.gif" />');
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).empty().html('£' + value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I think that an easy way to handle this one is to add something like a `loading` sub-observable to the observable that you are updating.  Then, set `loading` to true when you are starting your AJAX request.  Set `loading` to false when your data arrives.

Then, you can bind the visibility of your image to `yourobservable.loading`.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kyaKc/

Also, one tip about your custom bindings:  The binding's `update` function will only run again when any of the observables that have their value accessed are updated.  So, in your case it would only run when `price` is updated.  You could set the `price` to null before your AJAX request, then in your binding show the loading image when the value is null, otherwise show the actual value of your observable (which you would have updated when your AJAX request succeeded).

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for your help on this. How do I integrate this into a view model that alread exists?

Comment: Do you have some sample code or a fiddle?  You could add your `loading` observable anywhere really, so it does not need to be a sub-observable of the one that you are populating.

Comment: Hi Ryan, have sent you an example link as I dont know how to create a suitable example in Fiddle. Unfortunately I cant post a link to the site I'm working on yet.